Write the sum in terms of the Riemann zeta function
I believe it is a question from JHMT.
Write the sum $\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{gcd(a,b)}{(a+b)^3}$ in terms of Riemann zeta function. The answer should be $-Z(2)+\frac{Z(2)^2}{Z(3)}$where $Z(s)$ represents the zeta function. I have no idea how to obtain this answer.
Here is some of my attempts.
Let $r=gcd(a,b), a=a_0r, b=b_0r$ and  $gcd(a_0,b_0)=1$
Then
$\sum_{a=1}^\infty\sum_{b=1}^\infty\frac{gcd(a,b)}{(a+b)^3}$ = $\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{1}{r^2} \sum_{(a_0,b_0)=1}\frac{1}{(a_0+b_0)^3}$
And I don't know how to go further, maybe using the Möbius function?

What is "JHMT"?

Here's a trick that should avoid the annoying coprimality condition in the inner sum: write $\gcd(a,b) = \sum_{d\mid\gcd(a,b)} \phi(d)$.

It is a math tournament held by Johns Hopkins university. @GregMartin

Notice that
$$
\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)=n,
$$
so we have (all sums are over positive integers)
$$
\begin{aligned}
S
&=\sum_a\sum_b{\gcd(a,b)\over(a+b)^3}=\sum_d\sum_{a\equiv0\pmod d}\sum_{b\equiv0\pmod d}{\varphi(d)\over(a+b)^3} \\
&=\sum_d{\varphi(d)\over d^3}\sum_\mu\sum_\nu{1\over(\mu+\nu)^3}.
\end{aligned}
$$
To evaluate the sum over $\mu$ and $\nu$. Notice that the number of positive solutions to $\mu+\nu=k$ is precisely $k-1$, so
$$
\sum_\mu\sum_\nu{1\over(\mu+\nu)^3}=\sum_k{k-1\over k^3}=\zeta(2)-\zeta(3).
$$
Finally, using the identity $\sum_n\varphi(n)n^{-s}=\zeta(s-1)/\zeta(s)$, we conclude that
$$
S={\zeta(2)\over\zeta(3)}\cdot[\zeta(2)-\zeta(3)]={\zeta(2)^2\over\zeta(3)}-\zeta(2).
$$

Thank you! BTW do you know where to read the proof of the last identity?

The identity relating $\varphi(d)$ and $n$ translates to $\sum_d\varphi(d)d^{-s}\cdot\sum_k k^{-s}=\sum_n n^{1-s}$
